# XSLT 2 Reverse tokenized result

Tags: xml, xslt

I am a beginner attempting to work with XSLT 2.0 to move an XML file from one schema to another schema. I've had a lot of success with most of the document but one piece is holding me up. The input XML element is geographic information, for example:

```
<spatial>United States -- Washington -- Asotin county; United States -- Idaho;</spatial>
```

In the above example, we have two locations, going from macro to micro, separated by a semicolon (;). However, the resultant schema wants them in reverse order and each in it's own  tag, and separated by commas, i.e.:

```
<mods:geographic>Asotin county, Washington, United States</mods:geographic>
<mods:geographic>Idaho,  United States</mods:geographic>
```

We are currently using the following, which works but limits us to 6 possible options (fine for our test dataset but we have a large number of datasets to convert and no direct control over them):

```
<xsl:template match="spatial">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ';')">
        <xsl:variable name="spatialPart" select="tokenize(., ' -- ')"/>
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != ''">
                <!--spatialPart refers to each segment of a full place name; tokenize/separate each segment at space dash dash space-->            
                <geographic>
                    <xsl:value-of separator=", "
                        select="$spatialPart[6], $spatialPart[5], $spatialPart[4], $spatialPart[3], $spatialPart[2], $spatialPart[1]"
                    />
                </geographic>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm hoping to come up with something that can take any number of arguments. Based on other posts, I've tried working a numeric descending sort into this but it throws an error each time (I believe because it wants the sort to be the first instruction but I don't know how to reference it later if it is).

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="spatial">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ';')[normalize-space()]">
        <geographic>
            <xsl:value-of select="reverse(tokenize(., ' -- '))" separator=", "/>
        </geographic>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That worked for the first entry, the second wasn't changed. Here's the results:

`<geographic>Asotin county, Washington, United States</geographic>
<geographic> United States -- Idaho</geographic>`

    Edit: Sorry, I don't know how to get the comments to be as pretty as the original post :D

Comment: Those are not the results I see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Mvnt3v

Comment: I had to wrap the first tokenize argument in normalize-space as there were extra spaces on some entries--that was throwing it off. Marked as accepted, thank you!